# Erro usando classe phpMailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Estou fazendo um formulario de contatos usando a classe phpMailer e sempre que envio o email acontece este erro:

Estou usando a conexao SMTP.

"Fatal error: Class 'SMTP' not found in /home/proftpd/www@meudominio.com.br/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php on line 1466".

Abaixo segue codigo que estou usando:

```
<?php

// Inclui o arquivo class.phpmailer.php localizado na pasta phpmailer
require("./PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");


// Inicia a classe PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// Define os dados do servidor e tipo de conexão
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
$mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP
//$mail->Host = "localhost"; // Endereço do servidor SMTP (caso queira utilizar a autenticação, utilize o host smtp.seudomínio.com.br)
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Usar autenticação SMTP (obrigatório para smtp.seudomínio.com.br)
$mail->Username = 'site@dominio.com.br'; // Usuário do servidor SMTP (endereço de email)
$mail->Password = 'siteteste'; // Senha do servidor SMTP (senha do email usado)

// Define o remetente
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
$mail->From = "site@dominio.com.br"; // Seu e-mail
$mail->Sender = "site@dominio.com.br"; // Seu e-mail
$mail->FromName = "Ariel"; // Seu nome

// Define os destinatário(s)
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
$mail->AddAddress('site@dominio.com.br', 'Teste contato');


// Define os dados técnicos da Mensagem
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
$mail->IsHTML(true); // Define que o e-mail será enviado como HTML
//$mail->CharSet = 'iso-8859-1'; // Charset da mensagem (opcional)

// Define a mensagem (Texto e Assunto)
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
$mail->Subject  = "Mensagem Teste"; // Assunto da mensagem
$mail->Body = 'Este é o corpo da mensagem de teste, em HTML! 
 <IMG src="http://seudomínio.com.br/imagem.jpg" alt=":)"   class="wp-smiley"> ';
$mail->AltBody = 'Este é o corpo da mensagem de teste, em Texto Plano! \r\n 
<IMG src="http://seudomínio.com.br/imagem.jpg" alt=":)"  class="wp-smiley"> ';

// Define os anexos (opcional)
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
//$mail->AddAttachment("/home/login/documento.pdf", "novo_nome.pdf");  // Insere um anexo

// Envia o e-mail
$enviado = $mail->Send();

// Limpa os destinatários e os anexos
$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->ClearAttachments();

// Exibe uma mensagem de resultado
if ($enviado) {
echo "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
} else {
echo "Não foi possível enviar o e-mail.

";
echo "Informações do erro: 
" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

?>
```

Comment: uma pergunta boba, mas, você lembrou de copiar a `class.smtp.php` para a pasta do seu phpmailer? As classes `class.phpmailer.php` e `class.smtp.php` são necessárias pra utilizar a função.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No pacote do [`PHPMailer`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), existem diversas classes, entre as quais a: `class.smtp.php` utilizada no ficheiro `class.phpmailer.php`.

Dado que estás a incluir o ficheiro `class.phpmailer.php` no teu script, precisas incluir também as suas dependências:

```
require("./PHPMailer/class.smtp.php");
require("./PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
```

Na prática, a recomendação do PHPMailer é que incluas o *autoLoader* que faz auto-carregamento das classes necessárias, onde farias da seguinte forma:

```
require ("./PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
```

Incluindo o *autoLoader*, sempre que alguma classe é necessária e não está carregada, o *autoLoader* carrega a mesma por ti, evitando o teu problema.

Comment: A quem deu voto negativo, seria bom saber o que está errado com a resposta, para corrigir o problema!

Answer (score 4):

Tente isto

```
require_once (dirname(__FILE__) . '/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
```